# jquery plug in to add or remove class to a dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, delay

It is possible to create a jquery plug-in that allows to add or remove a specific class to a dom element, and onComplete call another function. I´m doing this to avoid the usage of a delay explained here: [css3 and jquery load page slider effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538279/css3-and-jquery-load-page-slider-effect)

Something that I could use like this:

```
myFunction('#domElement', addClass/removeClass, classToAddOrRemove, callBackFunctionOnComplete);
```

Comment: $(domElement).addClass(addClass).removeClass(removeClass) does not work?

Comment: Not sure what are you meaning but jQuery UI implements its own methods for `addClass/removeClass`, e.g: http://api.jqueryui.com/addclass/  Or you could just extend any specific jQuery methods. That's said, you would have better to explain clearly what you are looking for

Comment: Yes but I have to put a delay becouse the clases have transition, so I have to put a delay to works. But I have problems with some browsers in slow devices.

Comment: I´m creating an ajax load page with a slider effect. I explain that in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538279/css3-and-jquery-load-page-slider-effect

Comment: You can use `.delay()` and `.queue()` or a timeout. Could you provide a online sample replicating your issue?

Comment: It could be done with jquery UI with show(), hide(). But I want phones devices performance so I try to use css3

Comment: I don´t know how I´m new

Comment: @PabloLevin I think i misuderstood your issue, my bad!

Comment: I think to use a function that removeClass and on complete call other function that addClass

Comment: I guess you are looking for animationEnd/transitionEnd events, as in posted answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using css transitions to do this, so why not remove the class then check for all transition events to finish before running your callback.

http://jsfiddle.net/7cdh11qw/

```
var doClassyStuff = function(node, method, theClass, callback){
    $(node)[method](theClass);
    $(node).one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
        callback();
    });
}

doClassyStuff('#domElement', 'removeClass', 'someClass', function(){
    console.log("class removed");
});
```

Comment: I'd use `one()` not `bind()` but makes sense now ;)

Comment: `one()` not `on()` so avoiding binding multiple similar handlers

Comment: Its been a long day :)

Comment: Almost there but I don´t want white spaces, when I make the slider effect. So if I wait the transition to stop I have that problem

Comment: I use 5 clases to-screen, to-right, to-left, those with a transition of 0.8s and to-next, to-prev with out transition time

Comment: So when I want for an object to move from right to screen I do: $('#ajax-inserted1').removeClass('to-right').addClass('to-screen')

Comment: When I click next again i do this: $('#ajax-inserted2').removeClass('to-screen').addClass('to-left');  
                $('#ajax-inserted1').removeClass('to-right').removeClass('to-left').addClass('to-next').load(page, function(){  
                        setTimeout(doctorDelay, malfunctionDelay);
                        function doctorDelay() {
                            $('#ajax-inserted1').removeClass('to-next').addClass('to-screen');
                    }
                     
                });